# laravel attach() function looks for the table in the default database

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple databases in my laravel project with the default one named as **auth**. Most of the tables in my application are in the database **inventory**. Two tables in this database are `documents` and `items` having a many to many relationship. I use the laravel's `attach()` function to save records in a third table. But I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'auth.document_item' doesn't exist.
```

Any way I could define that the table `document_item` is also in the `inventory` database?

Comment: How is your relationship defined? You could possibly do something like `$this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'inventory.document._item')` to specify a custom table name for the relationship. You could also probably [define a custom intermediate table class](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Comment: Have you defined the connection on the model?

Comment: @Rwd yes, the two models have their connection defined

Comment: @apokryfos, adding the database name to the table name in belongsToMany() helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you

- Specify which connection every model is using using the  `$connection` property.
- Specify a custom pivot model in your `belongsToMany` relationship.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'auth';     // database name
    protected $table = 'documents';     // table name

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'document_item')->using(DocumentItem::class);
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'inventory'; // database name
    protected $table = 'items';          // table name

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Document::class, 'document_item')->using(DocumentItem::class);
    }
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class DocumentItem extends Pivot
{
    protected $connection = 'inventory'; // database name
    protected $table = 'document_item';  // table name

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Document::class);
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }
}
```